# Store other key's value in the dart model if first one is null - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, json-annotation

I'm using the `json_annotation` package to build my dart model.

I have a situation where I need to store either value from the API response in my `name` key.

API is returning two keys `alias` and `name`. In my model, I need to store the value in such a way that, if there is value in `alias`*(not null)* the `name` *(in model)* will have an `alias` value. Otherwise, the `name`*(from API)* key, will be stored in the model's `name` key.

**Code -**

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'nw_wealth.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(anyMap: true)
class NwWealth {
 final int accountId;
 final String name;
 final double current;
 final double invested;
 final double gain;
 final String type;
 final double gainPercent;
 final DateTime lastUpdated;

 NwWealth(
   this.name,  // this.name should be = alias ?? name;
   this.current,
   this.invested,
   this.gain,
   this.type,
   this.gainPercent,
   this.accountId,
   this.lastUpdated,
 );

 factory NwWealth.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
     _$NwWealthFromJson(json);

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$NwWealthToJson(this);
}
```

Is there a way, where I can store the actual name and alias into the same key in the model based on availability?

**I did check the `JsonKey()` object. But couldn't find a solution.**